# AVPlayer can't remove time observer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I'm working on video playback with `AVPlayer` and PIP(picture in picture) support. I found some crash when `dealloc` the `AVPlayer`. If player is in PIP state, and app call:

```
[self.player removeTimeObserver:self.timeObserver]`
```

The app will crash with below info.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An instance of AVPlayer cannot remove a time observer that was added by a different instance of AVPlayer.'

It only happens in PIP state and I check the `AVPlayer` doesn't change. Thanks, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you have retain cycle here. You can check controller of you retain or not. And before add an item you can try remove observer time before.